# Responsive Table issue with overflow on CSS

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I found a solution last time where I needed a table to be responsive through mobile. The solution was to place a div around the table and use overflow scroll. However, I need to update a load of templates that do not have the div class "tablewrapper" in them, so is there a way of setting the overflow scroll just on the table or tbody??

**Html Table Code**

```
<h3 class="showOnMobile">Swipe right or rotate your device to see full table</h3>
<div class="tablewrapper">
<table>
<tbody>
</tbody>
<thead>
<tr>
<th scope="col">Code</th>
<th scope="col">Colour</th>
<th scope="col">Capacity Litre</th>
<th scope="col">Height</th>
<th scope="col">Diameter</th>
<th scope="col">Weight</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td data-label="Code">123</td>
<td data-label="Colour">Stainless Steel</td>
<td data-label="Capacity Litre">45Ltr</td>
<td data-label="Height">0.65m</td>
<td data-label="Diameter">0.35m</td>
<td data-label="Weight">3.1kg</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

**CSS for tablewrapper**

```
.tablewrapper { 
    max-width:100vw;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    h3.showOnMobile { 
        display:none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am correct, you want to replace the **div class= tablewrapper** and want to apply styles directly on table right???
I removed the div and instead following styles to **table** tag itslef.

```
table { 
    max-width:100vw;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    display: block;
}
```

It worked the same. Please let me know if your issue was same or not.

Answer (score 0):

you can target the parent of the table :

```css
*:has(> table) {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

https://caniuse.com/css-has